# What is the meaning of '{**}' in Pathname#join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pathname

In my Rails project in `application.rb` file there is a line, which is written by some previous developer who was working on the project.

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'classes', '{**}')]
```

I know that `autoload_paths` is used by rails to load all required files. I am not able to figure out the meaning of `{**}`. Does this means all files and sub directories of classes directory will be loaded? Is there any documentation which I can refer for this.

I have done some debugging.

```
2.2.5 :008 > Rails.root.join('app', 'classes', '{**}')
 => #<Pathname:/home/tk/src/project-name/app/classes/{**}>
```

This is actually a [Pathname](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html) object. But I have not found any reference about `{**}` [here](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#method-i-join).

**Does any one have any idea what is `{**}`?**
**Is there any documentation for this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Pathname` just builds a path, it does not care about parts.

`**` is a parameter to `Dir#[]` which is eventually an alias to [`Dir#glob`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.2/Dir.html#method-c-glob).

`**` means “match directories recursively.”

Comment: Also, `{..}` is used for grouping and alternation in globs (e.g. `{foo,ba{r,z},q*}` should match `foo`, `bar`, `baz`, `quux` but not `charlie`). `{**}` should be identical to `**`.

Comment: @Amadan yes, indeed, `{**}` **is** identical to `**`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a feature of [`Dir.glob`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.2/Dir.html#method-c-glob), though I'm not sure why this is used the way it is here. `{...}` is a grouping mechanism, but there's only one element in it, `**`, which is a recursive matcher.

You should be fine with:

```
Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'classes', '**')]
```

Or if you like something more conscise:

```
Dir[Rails.root.join(*%w[ app classes ** ]]
```